# how to colour area under graph with negative values in Google Charts

Tags: google-visualization

I've added some negative values on the y axis of an area graph and noticed that the background colouring does not pull all the way down to -100 and stops at 0. I wondered if anyone knew how to do this as there doesn't seem to be much in the documentation in relation to altering this.

[image]

Comment: will you please share the code used to draw the chart?

Comment: You should set the vAxis.baseline option to -100.

Comment: Thanks for your reply guys. I just set the baseline to -100 and that pulled it right down. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

For people who stumbled on this question without reading the comment, here is the solution.

You need to set to set the `baseline` attribute of `vAxis` to `-100` or a number bigger than your data points.

```js
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
  const data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Time', 'Temp'],
      ['11h',  -9],
      ['14h',  -2],
      ['17h',  0],
      ['20h',  0],
      ['23h',  2],
      ['2h',  4],
      ['5h',  2],
      ['8h',  2]
  ]);

  const options = {
      legend: { position: 'none' },
      lineWidth: 3,
      title: 'Test',
      vAxis: {
          viewWindow: { min: -10, max: 5 },
          baseline: -100 // <-- add this
      },
      hAxis: {
          textStyle: { italic: true },
      },
      colors: ['#fdd663'],
      areaOpacity: 0.2,
      enableInteractivity: false,
      interpolateNulls: true
  };

  const chart = new google.visualization.AreaChart(document.getElementById('divChart'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>

<div id="divChart"></div>
```